# How to change bindings in the "choose action" menu in coc.nvim?

Tags: vim, key-bindings, vim-plugin, neovim, coc.nvim

**this is in my init.vim**

`nmap <leader>ca <Plug>(coc-codeaction-line)`

which opens a small menu of actions to choose from, i want to map said menu to use `<a-n>` for scrolling down and `<a-e>` for scrolling up

is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do key-mappings for menu by now, you can use `<C-f>` and `<C-b>` to scroll up/down. You can also use the follows:

- `g`: move to first menu item
- `G`: move to last item
- `j`: move to next
- `k`: move to preview item